# Meteor autoform without blaze?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

Is there some way or package that allows to generate forms from simpl-schema definitions outside the meteor ecosystem? I am looking for something like meteor-autoform to use in my project.

The package should allow:
validation
form generation
(table generation, like meteor-tabular) optionally

Comment: What means "outside" ? Using another framework or using Meteor with another rendering framework such as angular, react or vue?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I want to use it without meteor (in a nuxt.js project). I.e. blaze is not available

Comment: but then Meteor is the wrong context of question. You should rather ask in the context of  next / vue , if there is such functionality supported.

Comment: You should have a look at a set of React components: Vazco/Uniforms https://github.com/vazco/uniforms - it's not exactly the same, but it does some or all of what you are looking for. I would be interested to see what you think

Comment: @Mikkel Uniforms looks like what I am looking for. Unfortunately I am using vue and not react